# Primefaces calendar pop up with out year field

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In primefaces (Version 3) , can I make a calendar pop up having date and month only (no year selection is required).

Answer (score 0):

From the Primefaces User Guide 3.0:

> NAME  |  Default  |  Type  |  Description
>
> showOtherMonths | FALSE | Boolean | Displays days belonging to other months.
>
> selectOtherMonths | FALSE | Boolean | Enables selection of days belonging to
> other months.

This should hide the view and selection of other months, possibly preventing the selection of other years (it has to have a year, but maybe you can hide it from the user).

> yearRange | null | String | Year range for the navigator, default
> "c-10:c+10"

Perhaps you can use the `yearRange` attribute above in conjunction to limit the range to a single year as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mindate and maxdate attributes to restrict year selection:

```
<p:calendar mindate="#{dataItem.LOWER_RANGE}" maxdate="#{dataItem.UPPER_RANGE}"/>
```

Comment: But I need not to show the year over this popup(calendar display)